# Вывод меню на cms Umi

Tags: php, cms, umi

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом выводятся элементы меню в cms Umi?
Нужно поменять местами ссылки меню но нигде не могу найти файл...
       Вот код:

```
       <div class="container clear">
        <nav class="main-nav f-left">
            <div class="mobile-menu">
                <p>Главное меню</p>
                <div class="icon"></div>
            </div>
            <ul>    
                <?php
                foreach ($this->macros('content', 'menu', array(null, 4, false, false, 1))['items']['nodes:item'] as $item) {
        //                        $name = str_replace("Выполненные работы по лестницам","Выполненные работы", $item['@name']);
      //                        $name = str_replace("Блог лестничников","Статьи по лестницам", $name);

                    $active = (!is_null($pageCurrent) && $item['@id'] == $pageCurrent->getId()) || $item['@id'] == "3197" ? "class='active'" : "";

                    echo '<li ' . $active . '><a href="'.$item['@link'] . '">' . $item['@name'] . '</a>';

                    if ($item['items']['nodes:item'][0]) {
                        echo '<ul class="submenu">';
                        foreach ($item['items']['nodes:item'] as $child) {
                            echo '<li><a href="'.$child['@link'] . '">' . $child['@name'] . '</a>';

                            if ($child['items']['nodes:item'][0]) {
                                echo '<ul class="submenu">';
                                foreach ($child['items']['nodes:item'] as $child2) {
                                    echo '<li><a href="'.$child2['@link'] . '">' . $child2['@name'] . '</a>';

                                    if ($child2['items']['nodes:item'][0]) {
                                        echo '<ul class="submenu">';
                                        foreach ($child2['items']['nodes:item'] as $child3) {
                                            echo '<li><a href="'.$child3['@link'] . '">' . $child3['@name'] . '</a></li>';
                                        }
                                        echo '</ul>';
                                    }
                                    echo '</li>';
                                }
                                echo '</ul>';
                            }
                            echo '</li>';
                        }
                        echo '</ul>';
                    }
                    echo "</li>";
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не уверен, что понял верно вопрос, но меню генерируется на основе дерева сайта и в файле не хранится

Answer (score 0):

Последовательность вывода элементов для макроса content/menu определяется позицией страницы в структуре сайта.

Для того, чтобы изменить порядок следования ссылок в меню измените порядок страниц в модуле (Структура)[https://www.umi-cms.ru/product/modules/content/].
Или используйте для создания меню модуль (Меню)[https://www.umi-cms.ru/product/modules/menu/]